# Use scala manipulate rdd get the words count from Sharespeare.txt to verb dict

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

the verb_dict.txt contains things like that

***abash,abash,abashed,abashed,abashes,abashing***

***abate,abate,abated,abated,abates,abating***

***abide,abide,abode,abode,abides,abiding***

**......**

Shakespeare text just 5MB article

every word have 6 tense the question is once met different tense in the text but need to count to original tenst

Use learned RDD operations to merge the verb pairs that are from the same verb. E.g. (work, 100),
(works,50), (working,150) ----> (work, 300).

my idea is group things like [(verb_in_different_tense,(original_tense,count))] I don't know if that works just give a think about it

**My code shows below:**

`val shakes = sc.textFile("shakespeare.txt")` to create rdd from txt file

`val shakes1 = shakes.filter(l => l.length > 0)`  remove empty line

`val shakes2 = shakes1.map(x=>x.replaceAll("""[\p{Punct}]""",""))`  remove the punctuations

`val shakes3 = shakes2.flatMap(line=>line.split(" "))` split by space will make each words into one partition

`val shakes4 = shakes3.filter(_.nonEmpty)` get the nonEmpty line

`val shakes5 = shakes4.filter(w=>w == w.toLowerCase())` to lower case

**This is done for Shakespeare.txt file**

then need to Use learned RDD operations to merge the verb pairs that are from the same verb. E.g. (work, 100),
(works,50), (working,150) ----> (work, 300).

can anyone give me specific steps to deal with this question please?

Answer (score 0):

There are another questions related to this topic and they are related to NLP tasks. What you need here is to extract the lemmas of those words and put them in another column and then group by that column.

Take a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(morphology)

You can use the Stanford NLP library to perform the lemmatizer to your words(tokens). An example of how you can use in Java that you can use without problems in Scala: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/lemma.html

In this repo you can see how you can use Stanford CoreNLP in Spark https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp.

Or you can use the annotation from SparkNLP project https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/annotators